# any idea why js errors aren't showing up in my firebug console?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

I'm having to open the firefox error console, which is kind of annoying.

Comment: firefox version #, firebug version # = ???

Comment: Please give more information, there's not enough to answer the question unless someone else has run into the exact same situation.

Comment: Sorry. It' Firebug 1.2.1 and FireFox 3.0. I'm not doing anything extraordinary, though I'm using a fair bit of memory (225 mb). I'm going to restart and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restart seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Open Firebug, and under the Console tab, check "Console" and "Script", then hit "Apply for *domain.com*".

Comment: Thanks tj111. The console's already applied though. I've been logging to the console (console.log). It's just js errors that aren't working.